# Reusableforms Set from email to posted email

Tags: phpmailer

I have implemented Reusableforms on my site, everything is working fine apart from when I view received emails in the client, the emails are always from 'contact form' with the email 'forms@domain.com'.

How can I change this to display the senders name and email that is posted via the form? Here is the code from the handler.php included with reusableforms.

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

 */
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler();

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['Name','Email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('Email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('Message')->maxLength(6000);


$pp->requireReCaptcha();
$pp->getReCaptcha()->initSecretKey('0000000000000000000000000000000');


$pp->sendEmailTo('orders@domain'); // ← Your email here


echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

Comment: On further investigation if I edit the FormHandler.php file to post the name and email, it does so and the email is received, but the form still states sending and does not return a success message. For reference, this is the particular form I'm using http://reusableforms.com/d/b/php-contact-form-with-validation-and-recaptcha

Comment: There's not enough info here - I suggest you contact reusableforms.

Comment: I tried that, and ironically, their contact form doesn't work.....

Answer (score 0):

I too been looking for help on this very subject.

I have got this to work - by chance - by having two instances of
'$pp = new FormHandler();'.

See my version of the code below.

I do not understand why it works.

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;

$pp = new FormHandler();

/* The next 7 lines must be in this 1st section */

$mailer = $pp->getMailer();
$mailer->IsSMTP();
$mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$mailer->SMTPSecure ="ssl";
$mailer->Host = "serverxxx.xxxx.com";
$mailer->Username = "contact@xxxxxxx.com";
$mailer->Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

/* The next 2 lines work whether in the 1st or 2nd section */

$pp->requireReCaptcha();
$pp->getReCaptcha()->initSecretKey('xxxxxxxxxxxx');

/* Section 2 
I do not understand it, but without the 2nd '$pp = new FormHandler()' below,
the SMTP send fails. The reported error is:

Sorry there was an error sending your form.
mail:SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

I have tested changing the 2nd $pp to $pp2 and it also works.
*/

$pp = new FormHandler(); 

/* The next line has to be in this 2nd section.
If it is the last line in top section then it appears to be sent OK
but the email does not actually arrive. 
Checking the SMTP logs shows it was never sent.*/

$pp->sendEmailTo(['leslie@xxxxxxxxxxx.com']);

/* The next 2 lines also must be here rather than in 1st section above. */

$mailer = $pp->getMailer();
$mailer->setFrom('contact@xxxxxxx.com','xxxxxxx Contact Form');

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a reply to the user email address on a ReusableForm, you'll need to get the value from the handler.php and add that to FormHandler.php above the 'setFrom' function using the addReplyTo function &  $_POST global variable:

```php
$this->mailer->addReplyTo($_POST['Email']); 

$this->mailer->setFrom($from_email,'Contact Form',false);
```

These forms still work well in 2021 using PHP 7.3